# OpenOCD connection with STM32F1x and ST-Link

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, stm32, openocd

I am using STM32F103. I want to use OpenOCD to flash STM32. I was using keil but I want to shift to arm-gcc compiler.
I can compile the code for the controller. But now I want to flash it using OpenOCD. 
I was able to manage its configurations.

Here are the logs on openocd connection.

```
X:\Work\OToggle>openocd -f led_Debug.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00021-g524e8c8 (2019-04-12-08:48)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst
none separate
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v17 API v2 SWIM v4 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.245003
Error: BUG: can't assert SRST
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 700ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 1500ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 3100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 6300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 6300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 6300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 6300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 6300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 300ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : stm32f1x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 0 watchpoints
Error: mem2array: Read @ 0xe0042004, w=4, cnt=1, failed
mem_helper.tcl:6: Error:
in procedure 'mmw'
in procedure 'mrw' called at file "mem_helper.tcl", line 16
at file "mem_helper.tcl", line 6

Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Error: TRST/SRST error
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0800115c msp: 0x20005000
Info : device id = 0x20036410
Info : flash size = 64kbytes
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffb
Warn : ignoring character 0x1f
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffb
Warn : ignoring character 0x20
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffb
Warn : ignoring character 0x18
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffb
Warn : ignoring character 0x27
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffd
Warn : ignoring character 0x1
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffb
Info : The target is not running when halt was requested, stopping GDB.
Warn : ignoring character 0xffffffff
Warn : ignoring character 0xfffffffd
Info : The target is not running when halt was requested, stopping GDB.
Warn : ignoring character 0xd
Warn : ignoring character 0xa
Warn : keep_alive() was not invoked in the 1000ms timelimit. GDB alive packet not sent! (1072). Workaround: increase "set remotetimeout" in GDB
Warn : ignoring character 0x77
Warn : ignoring character 0x72
Warn : ignoring character 0x69
Warn : ignoring character 0x74
Warn : ignoring character 0x65
Warn : ignoring character 0x20
Warn : ignoring character 0x66
Warn : ignoring character 0x6c
Warn : ignoring character 0x61
Warn : ignoring character 0x73
Warn : ignoring character 0x68
Warn : ignoring character 0xd
Warn : ignoring character 0xa
Warn : keep_alive() was not invoked in the 1000ms timelimit. GDB alive packet not sent! (1108). Workaround: increase "set remotetimeout" in GDB
```

I have tried the following things:

1. I opened a second command prompt and gave following command

   ```
   arm-none-eabi-gdb led.elf
   ```

   But then it started gdb session (**I never used it**)
2. I tried to connect the target through putty (2-3 years back I was using this method to connect an nRF51).

This time, both methods didn't work.

Comment: Make your life a bit easier and install atollic studio or STMCUBEMXIDE. Those IDEs do the boring job (like debug configurations) for you.

Comment: I was using Keil and CubeMx to generate the code. But i changed to linux os and i don't have keil available on linux os. I am using STM's Standard Peripheral Library.
This will help me to use it nRF51 as well.

Comment: I work with STM32 MCU-s under GNU/Linux. I use [stlink-org/stlink](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink) (former texane/stlink) to debug with gdb. Give it a try.

Comment: @P__J__ - Best idea. I just noticed that both STM32CubeMX / STM32CubeIDE and Atollic TrueStudio are available for Linux, too.

Comment: @dev_eng - If you are wondering whether to prefer TrueStudio or STM32CubeIDE as a new GUI, you should start with STM32CubeIDE because STM has bought TrueStudio in order to merge it into "its" STM32CubeIDE and abandon it some day, I guess. Anyway, on Windows, both IDEs worked for me out-of-the-box, so I guess they'll do on your Linux machine, too.

Comment: i have configured the gcc compiler and i can compile it. For now problem is only OpenOCD is not configured. Alternately i am using st-link flasher to flash.